# Delphi 11.3 runtime error 217 while not in IDE

Tags: delphi, runtime-error

My problem is, when I run my application from the IDE then everything works correctly, but if I try to start the application from File Explorer then I get runtime error 217 in both Debug and Release modes.

Can anyone help me to find out why this error is happening?

I search the address displayed in the error message, but it is not in the `.map` file.

Comment: This is a windows error. It might indicate a corrupted file system. Google it for more info.

Comment: This is not a windows error @eirik it's a Delphi rtl error. I think it's an access violation during unit initialization.

Comment: Use a tool like EurekaLog, madExcept or Deleaker

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution:
I installed EurekaLog and an error during initialization was pointed at Skia. I uninstalled Skia4Delphi and then the application worked correctly.
I don't use Skia in this application but I tested Skia so Skia was one of the units used by my main form. I found this reference while doing a build. I remove the reference and after that no more error.

Comment: Same goes on Delphi 12. By some reason SKIA was in Uses clause, and it crashing on different computer. Absolutely awful, and Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Runtime error 217 is thrown when an unhandled exception is raised before the exception handling framework is installed at startup, or after it is removed at shutdown.

So most likely the error is being caused in Initialization section of one of your units.

Do you use initialization sections in your code? Try using ShowMessages to
catch the moment when the bug occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enabled your project! Right click -> Enable Skia?